# How to do this email Validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to make my email validation do exactly this

```
combination of letters (both upper & lower case), numbers and periods
single at symbol @ 
combination of letters (both upper & lower case), numbers, hyphens and/or periods
single period
combination of 2 – 4 letters (lower case only)
```

This is what I have and please correct me if I am wrong.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uk6cD/3/

Comment: Just use `/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/` and do the rest on the serverside

Comment: The last part `combination of 2 – 4 letters` is going to cause issues: some TLD's are longer than 4 characters and don't forget asian TLD's.

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses can be *complicated*, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address for an introduction and then the various RFCs (espesially https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6530.)

As a javascript client, I would just make sure an atsign '@' is present and surrounded by some text.  Something like

```
/^.+@.+$/
```

or without regex

```
var isValid = email.length >= 3 && email.indexOf('@') >= 0;
```

Here's a list some *complicated* email address; http://rumkin.com/software/email/test.php

Answer (score -2):

Your regex shoud be as simple as

```
var valid = email.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]){1,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Fails RFC 6530.  This regex would reject  甲斐@黒川.日本

Comment: "as simple as" hehe, regex, always simple :D

Comment: @MikeGrabowski Well, actually the regex is following the format needed by the poster

Comment: @RichardSchneider I don't care, the poster asked for a given known format

Answer (score -3):

```
a= "xxxxx@example.com"
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if (!filter.test(a))
{
  alert("correct")
}
else
 {
  alert("incorrect email id")
 }
```

Comment: Fails RFC 6530. This regex would reject 甲斐@黒川.日本

Comment: this is only for English if u want different language means u can use this way "/^([startingchar-endchar])+\@(([startingchar-endchar]+\.)+([startchar-endchar])+$/"

Comment: @kama, Email addresses are NOT ENGLISH end of story.

Comment: An address at TLD is also valid, such as "foo@org".  Your regex would reject it.  I suggest reading the relevent RFCs or at least @ZippyV comment.

Comment: ya foo@org is invalid mail id. you dont give proper domain name. this is correct way foo@xxx.org

Comment: Read the spec, "foo@org" is valid.  What about an IPv4 or IPv6 for the domain name?

Comment: can u send the link of this real time example

Comment: See my answer for a list of interesting email addresses.

Comment: k till now i didn't see this type of mail id .if u want use special case mail id means u can use query string whatever u want to validate in if-else statement